# Granting permissions on SQL SERVER user defined functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

If user defined functions are never executed outside the context of a stored procedure, what are the reasons one might grant permissions on SQL Server user defined functions?

Should we add grant permissions when developing database creation scripts that involve creating UDFs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user defined function can be used outside the context of stored procedures.  It is good practice to allow this granularity in database object security.
I prefer to have permissions involving roles (data reader, data writer, reports, etc.) then yes use grant permission using the creation scripts.
Take a look at this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx